# MongoDB data modelling: any drawbacks in using lots of databases?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, data-modeling

I have recently moved to MongoDB part of the back-end of a web app, the web app itself is a validation tool, and the workflow looks like:

- the user uploads a file (typically hundreds of thousands of lines)
- the validator checks it outputting a lot of messages (possibly more than one per line)
- ...and finally provide a few statistics

I modelled my application so that each user has it's own DB containing:

- The file (saved through GridFS)
- A collection containing the messages (possibly over a million lines, in some cases)
- A collection with the statistics

We have a few hundreds of users, so **MongoDB will end up having a few hundreds DBs**.

Of course I could have hold all the data in the same DB, using namespaces to separate data from different users. However I felt it was handy to send the DB in the connection URI, and I found more intuitive to issue a "drop database" statement to purge a user, rather than searching and removing its data in the large DB.

I am pretty new to MongoDB, so my question is: **is there any drawback in having several DBs in the same MongoDB instance? Or is there any special consideration that I should give to the problem?**

Comment: AFAIK, there is a setting for the maximum number of databases of 24000 - but that can be raised. Judging from that number, a few hundred DBs should not be a problem.

Comment: @ppeterka - I might be wrong, but I believe that number is the max number of namespaces per object, so having separate DB's actually makes possible for me to store more data than if I had a single DB with 3 namespaces per user (`userA.messages,`userA.statistics`, etc..)... But maybe I misunderstood the documentation on that?

Comment: @ppeterka The limit applies per database ns file, MongoDB has no explicit limitation on its number of databases.

Comment: There is one I cna think of: file count and amount of open files, all OS' tend to have some kind of limit as to exactly how many open files you can have, having many databases on one server might hit that limit and then you will see problems. The other problems I can think of are mitigated by your use of the databases as completely separate entities.

Comment: Setting ulimit to a high number, like 64000, on Ubuntu/Debian will probably keep you from hitting the open file limit.

Comment: One drawback from this approach, that might not affect you, is that it would be more difficult to run statistics over several users, you'll need to pull the data from each user and then combine it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MongoDB specifically. In general, openning a connection to a database is a relatively slow operation and ties up system resources. Whether this is enough to matter in your case I can't say.

Having a different db for each user would make it difficult to perform queries that access data for multiple users. Maybe you have no need to do this.

Still, I would think it would be a whole lot simpler in general to just put a user id in each record rather than create a separate database. What's the gain of separate databases? Okay, deleting a user means saying "drop database". But deleting a user from a single database should mean saying "delete from tableX where user=?; delete from tableY where user=?" etc for however many relevant tables you have. I can't imagine it's hundreds, right? Maybe half a dozen lines of code or so?

Comment: Hi Jay. I would expect a datastore like Mongo, lacking a schema, to be heaps more efficient in opening a DB than a relational database... but maybe I'm plain wrong on this one? About your second para: making impossible to mix data from different users is a plus, in my scenario. Beside this, because of the way MongoDB URI works [host:port/dbname], one of the advantages of having a DB per user is is that I can pass the information in the URI (particularly handy for interprocess communication). But yeah: if the advantages were overwhelming, I would not have bother asking in the first place! :)

Comment: RE data from multiple users: I was thinking that at some point you might want to run queries to answer questions like, "What is the total number of uploaded files that we have from all users?" "What is the most common validation message? Do we have validation messages that have never been used?" "Which users have uploaded a file within the past week?" Etc. Maybe you don't care about such things and never will, but if it's even possible, that would be a lot easier with a single database.