# Mongoose multitenancy - handling document references + populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multi-tenant

I've read a bunch about multitenancy setup options in Mongoose/MongoDB. The options are:

1. Separate databases. This is a no-no because of the overhead per database instance
2. Prefixed collections in the same database - I would have `tenant1_Products` and `tenant2_Products` which share the same schema.
3. Standard collections with a reference back to the `tenant` document.

It seems to be that #2 is the best option for scaling, since it allows for easy sharding by prefix. So, assuming that, I would implement something like this to dynamically retrieve the model for a certain tenant:

```
tenant.methods.getModel = function(name) {
    return mongoose.model(this.uniqid + '_' + name);
}
```

Assuming I register all models for all tenants ahead of time with the correct schema, then I could do `var productModel = myTenant.getModel('Product');`, and then create/update from there.

The problem with this is when you need to implement document references to make use of Mongoose's `populate` method. E.g.,

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    categories:[
        {
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            // This will need to change to "tenant1_Category", etc
            ref:'Category'
        }
    ]
});
mongoose.model('tenant1_Product', productSchema);
tenant1.getModel('Product').find().populate('categories').exec(function(err, results) {
    ...
});
```

Essentially for this you'd need either need to make the `ref` property dynamic (IE, a function) that returns a different collection name depending upon some variable that defines the current tenant, or you could keep it static but find some way of telling the `populate` method to automatically add the appropriate prefix.

What is the best way of accomplishing this? Or, does it make more sense to go with option #3 above to avoid these issues? If so, does that have an effect on sharding/scaling methods?

Comment: I like the simplicity of a function `tenant()` + name. But, it's going to depend on how many collections that would end up creating?

Comment: Well I'd have to add that functionality and send a pull request if I were to go with the `ref=function()` route. Another option would be to modify the `ref` properties in each schema as I register them for a tenant. Question is, would having 15 schemas defined per tenant cause memory issues if we get up to several hundred tenants? I guess that would be a good problem to have.

Comment: A pull request, for what? `ref: tenant() + 'Category`?

Comment: That's not too many. Here's something to consider: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/#large-number-of-collections

Comment: @WiredPrairie `tenant()` would be executed right when the schema is defined, and not every time the schema is used. I need it to be essentially dynamic per request since the request data determines which tenant it is.

Comment: Ahh. I didn't understand how you were running the process. I'd imagined one per tenant. I see your point now. You'd need to have models based on tenants. Given that, I'd consider having multiple databases ... although I've never tried that with Mongoose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221236/mongodb-data-modelling-any-drawbacks-in-using-lots-of-databases

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in this, I went ahead and created a package that handles all of this, since I couldn't find an existing one.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-multitenant

It uses separate collections per tenant and compiles the schema as needed, optionally modifying the `ref` attributes for related documents to keep it within the tenancy.

Comment: As my use case needs extra security, separate collections is not enough, I had to go with separate databases, which is harder to manage from a connection point of view.